# Starting and stopping multiple processes in sync with each other

Tags: linux, terminal, synchronization, timeout, kill

I'll start with what I'm trying to achieve and then share what I've tried so far.

I have a process that we'll call someProcess. By calling

> ./someProcess &

I can create an instance of someProcess and put it to sleep immediately. Then, when

> killall -10 someProcess

is called, the process will wake up and run until it receives:

> killall -12 someProcess

This is all fine, but the goal is more complicated. I'd like to be able to create x number of sleeping instances of someProcess. I'd like to send all instances signal 10 at the same time (as close to simultaneous as possible), and 5 seconds later, I want to send all processes signal 12.

I've experimented with timeout quite a bit, and I think it would be possible to achieve this with timeout, but I can't figure out how. I can only get parts of the goal situation to work. I can get all instances to run for 5 seconds, and I can get all to receive a signal after that duration, but I can't figure out how to send two signals separated by a delay using timeout. Ideally, the situation would look something like this:

> ./someProccess &
>
> ./someProcess &
>
> ./someProcess &
>
> ...
>
> **Magical timeout command**
>
> //all instances of someProcess receive signal 10
>
> //5s pass
>
> //all instances of someProcess receive signal 12

The reason this needs to be done with one command is so that I can duplicate my results. I'd like to be able to test the behavior of someProcess when there are varying numbers of instances.

Comment: As close as possible. I'd like all instances to wake up simultaneously (or as close to "simultaneously" as possible), run for 5 seconds, then terminate.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip.